How can i print a pdf en c#?
I have to print a pdf in c# .NET 6.0.29 from my api. I was able to generate the pdf with ItextSharp but I can't print it.I know how to ping the printer and I have the correct name. It is well connected to the network, I have the rights to print.
Here is the error I have System.Drawing.Printing.Invalid PrinterException
Here is what I do:
private static bool PrintPdf(string filePath, string printerIpAddress)
{
    string printerName = printerIpAddress;
    try
    {
        using (var document = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument())
        {

            var printerSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
            printerSettings.PrinterName = printerName;


            document.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;

            document.PrintPage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Log.Information("Événement PrintPage déclenché");
                try
                {

                    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        
                        using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream))
                        {
                           
                            e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, e.MarginBounds);
                        }
                        
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                  
                    Log.Error("Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier PDF : " + ex.Message);
                }
            };
            
                document.Print();
      
                return true;

            
            
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidPrinterException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception InvalidPrinterException : " + ex.Message);
        Debug.WriteLine("StackTrace : " + ex.StackTrace);
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Erreur lors de l'impression du document : " + ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
   
     

}

}

Would you mind share the full stacktrace from that exception? You are trying to print to a network printer but more details need to be shared as we are unaware of your network environment.

StackTrace : System.Drawing.Printing.InvalidPrinterException: Settings to access printer 'prduf005' are not valid.
at System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmodeInternal(String printer)
at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.OnStartPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)
at System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController.OnStartPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)
at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document)
at ws_tickets.Service.PrinterService.PrintPdf(String filePath, String printerIpAddress)

If it's a shared network printer that is attached to the PC via USB, serial or parallel port then this is where you would need to share it and access it via \servername\printername. Please also keep in mind that the printer has to be installed on the computer you intend to use it. Just because it's a shared printer doesn't mean you can use it via \servername\printername without first installing it.

I still have the error, but looking further I noticed that this is what was throwing the exception: The property 'IsPlotter' of 'printerSettings' raised an exception of type 'System.Drawing.Printing.InvalidPrinterException'."

'IsPlotter' shouldn't be related to the issue so close as when System.Drawing.Printing is getting or setting Printer information it will check if Printer is valid first. If it is invalid, it will throw an InvalidPrinterException.I will suggest checking if that network shared printer is properly installed and use PrinterSettings.IsValid property to check if the configuration for the printer is correct.

I found the problem, thank you for your help
